# Python get imported modules from source code returned by inspect.getsource

Tags: python, reflection

I'm using `inspect.getsource` to retrieve the source code of functions. However, since some variables are imported at top level of the module containing the functions, it is not returned by `inspect.getsource`. For example, if we have

```
import numpy as np
def sqrt(x):
    return np.sqrt(x)
```

then `inspect.getsource(sqrt)` will not return the line `import numpy as np`. Is it possible to automatically retrieve what `np` here refers to? The import can also be other forms, such as `from some_module import some_func`, `from some_module import *`, `import some_module as some_name`.

Right now I'm using this function in trace function called by `sys.settrace`, so the solution can be both static (without running the code) or dynamic (when running the code, such as examining the frames).